# nested controllers, parent access and "controllerAs" syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some issues using `controllerAs` syntax (I try to follow johnpapa's style guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y032) and nested controllers.

Lets see at first the "regular" `$scope` syntax: http://plnkr.co/edit/S8jgE6hlQiYGsQYryxA2?p=preview
There are 2 controllers: `parentController` and `childController`. In `parentController` there is an object `obj` bound to `$scope`. `childController` access this object, and sets a property `name` (I need to write something from child to parent).

Now I try to do this same using `controllerAs` syntax: http://plnkr.co/edit/by9EAThEky7q0lKepv2r?p=preview
But I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined`.
`childController` doesn't see `obj`. Why? Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In `childController`, you are doing this:

```
var vm = this;
vm.obj.name = "child";
```

But, you're never setting the value of `obj` before trying to set the name property.

Try:

```
var vm = this;
vm.obj = {};
vm.obj.name = "child";
```

If you'd like to send the value of child up to the parent scope, you can use `$emit` to do this with events.  See this plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/huvcFN4JoTu3cBPSSPdQ?p=preview

Comment: OK, but isn't visible in `parentController`

Comment: parent controller cannot access child scope. You have to make a service or emit some kind of event that can bubble to the parent scope.

Comment: By using controllerAs syntax, you are binding to the controller instance, which isn't sharing $scope.  Its actually one of the benefits of controllerAs syntax because it allows you to see what object you're setting $scope values to.

Comment: Check this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4POxWY25WODblEl2oCOP?p=preview

Assume that, when we click "get message", we want to get  `message` property from `childController`. How to achieve it?  
If want to use $emit\$broadcast I still need to inject $scope: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/61 Anyway, how to do this "clean" with events? I need to brodcast my button click and then emit `message` back? Or maybe with service: every time when `message` in `childController` change (watch it with $watch?) set the value, then get it when user click the button? What do you think?

Comment: OK, I wrote this with service and `$watch`: http://plnkr.co/edit/7BHkEs9IIK28bGNt2wPa?p=preview

Comment: Updated my answer with a plunk using events